Rectangle property of arithmetic
I just want to know what this theorem I noticed is called by mathematicians.

$s_1+i_a=e_1$
$s_2+i_a=e_2$
$s_1+i_b=s_2$

Statements 1-3 imply that $e_1+i_b=e_2$.
It also works nicely for modular systems where the following also follow from statements 1-3:

$e_1+(modulus-i_a)=s_1$
$e_2+(modulus-i_a)=s_2$
$s_2+(modulus-i_b)=s_1$

And statements 4-6 imply that $e_2+(modulus-i_b)=e_1$.
There is a nice interpretation as a rectangle. What do mathematicians call this, if anything? Does this have implications outside of arthimetic, such as in geometry?
I named the variables from the ideas start, end, interval.

In general terms, you are eliminating $,\color{#c00}{s_2},,\color{#0a0}{s_1},$ which can trivially be done by substitution since the system of linear equations is in diagonal form, yielding $,e_2 = i_a + (\color{#c00}{i_b, +, }(\color{#0a0}{-i_a + e_1})) = i_b + e_1\ \ $

The reason I was interested in this, is because I noticed in music theory, if we consider any pair of identical intervals, there is guaranteed to be associated a second pair of identical intervals. And the modular arithmetic also allows for inversions.
For example the interval from E to C is a minor sixth and the interval from A to F is a minor sixth. This implies that the interval from E to A is the same as the interval from C to F, both being a perfect fourth. And the inversions have the same relations ship C to E and F to A are both major thirds and F to C and A to E are both perfect fifths. So this is just commutativity of multiplication in modular arithmetic. (In the original question: A=$s_1$, F=$e_1$, E=$s_2$, C=$e_2$, minor sixth = $i_a$, perfect fourth = $i_b$.
I think what I am noticing is commutativity of addition, this is why I called the idea a rectangle theorem. I have to rename the variables to get the intuition. $s_1=a,s_2=c_2,i_a=b_1,i_b=b_2,e_1=c_1,e_2=d$.
Imagine in general these coordinates are vectors and $a$ is an origin.
Start with $a+b_1=c_1$ and $a+b_2=c_2$.
$b_1$ and $b_2$ are two vectors emanating from $a$, and they terminate at $c_1$ and $c_2$.
Now add a vector emanating from the endpoint $c_2$ and terminating at $d$:
$c_2+b_1=d$
Notice that this also implies (the theorem):
$c_1+b_2=d$
But if we look at the two possible vector additions where $a$ is an origin and $d$ is the final endpoint:
$a+b_2+b_1=d$
$a+b_1+b_2=d$
So, we are showing commutativity of vector addition.
